# How do i delay this function

Tags: javascript, function, href, delay

I have this code:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);

  return false;
});
```

But I need a **600ms** delay after click the link so my page have chance to perform other actions that I set to **500ms**, thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has a [`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').delay(600).animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I love jQuery. http://needsmorejquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
setTimeout(function()
{

// Things to do after 600ms

},600);

$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});
```